# Matlab: Cannot convert EditField(text) into arrays or matrix

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure

I try to make a project for college. My task is to enter in the `EditFields(Text)` two separate values for the 3 examples below. If it's a scalar, I have to enter 2 numbers, if it's a vector(array) to enter 2 arrays and if it's a matrix, to enter 2 matrixes. Everything went well until I try to enter 2 arrays or matrixes in the `EditFields(Text)`. I tried different ways like [1, 2, 3] or [1 2 3] or 1 2 3 etc, but every time I got either the error

> Error setting property 'Data' of class 'Table':
> Data within a cell array must have size [1 1]

or

> Error setting property 'Data' of class 'Table': Values within a cell array must be numeric, logical, or char

The results should be shown into the table from bottom right. I tried to convert the values like this:

```
newRow = {selectedFunction, result};
if isnumeric(result)
    newRow{2} = result;
elseif ischar(result)
    newRow{2} = {result};
else
  
    uialert(app.UIFigure, 'Eroare: Tip de date neacceptat pentru adăugarea la tabel!', 'Eroare', 'Icon', 'error');
    return;
end
app.ResultTable.Data = [app.ResultTable.Data; newRow];
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: It is unclear what you intend to accomplish. You cannot put two arrays into an edit field.

Comment: I have two EditFields(text) where I try to input one array for each EditField but I receive this error: Error setting property 'Data' of class 'Table':
Data within a cell array must have size [1 1]

Error in app1/ExecuteButtonPushed (line 312)
        app.ResultTable.Data = newRow;

Error in matlab.apps.AppBase>@(source,event)executeCallback(ams,app,callback,requiresEventData,event) (line 62)
            newCallback = @(source, event)executeCallback(ams, ...
 
Error while evaluating Button PrivateButtonPushedFcn.

Comment: I have to do the following: - Study the functions plus, uplus, minus, uminus, times, rdivide, Idivide, power, mtimes and build a GUI application in MATLAB using AppDesigner.
The GUI is required to include:
• A list-type graphic object (ListBox) with the names of the functions for selecting the desired function.

Comment: • Graphical objects needed to read input arguments like this:
• 3 radio buttons specifying whether the reading arguments are scalars, vectors or matrices
• When evaluating the expressions, it is checked if the reading is correct for the input data and if the operands have the same size. Otherwise, some error messages are required to be displayed through modal dialog boxes.

Comment: • A Table graphic object for displaying the results
• An axis-type graphic object in which the values ​​of the input arguments and the result will be represented with different colors. If you work with scalars, markers of different colors will be drawn, if you work with vectors, only lines of different colors will be used, if they are matrices, then the representation is done only for the result using the Matlab imshow function.

Comment: Everything works just fine, just the problems with the EditFields(text) inside the graphic interface where I try to input any array cause problems. When I try to input just numbers, everything works well, axes, tables etc